# Append to new line

Tags: linux, append, newline

I have a bunch of  *.rpm files in a directory and want to append each iteration from my for loop to a new line in a file. How do I do it? The problem is that with the current output, all the output is written to the first line leaving the other lines blank. I want the output of what i run in each file to be output in a new line in "x.txt".

Here is what I have:

```
for i in *;do
    rpm --queryformat "%{NAME} %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{SourceRPM}  %{Summary} %{Group} %{URL} %{ARCH}" -qp  "$i"   ;
done  >> x.txt
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you getting error messages for the other files? You're only writing `stdout` to the file, not `stderr`.

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit surprised that rpm does not add newlines. You can just add one manually, though.

Example without newlines:

```
$ rm -f a.txt ; for i in 1 2 3; do echo -n $i ; done >> a.txt
$ cat a.txt
123$
```

Example with newlines:

```
$ rm -f a.txt ; for i in 1 2 3; do echo -n $i ; echo ; done >> a.txt
$ cat a.txt
1
2
3
$
```

Comment: Hello,I do not understand. What should I change in my code?

Comment: @airzinger1 He's suggesting that you add an `echo` command after the `rpm` command, to add a newline

Comment: The point of this answer is, you can add the extra instruction `echo ` for every iteration. This implicitly add a newline to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information you posted in your question, you just have to add an empty `echo` instruction at the end of each iteration. This action adds a new line at the end of the output produced by each iteration, as @smoe tried to explain with a simplified example.

Adapting it to the posted code in your question:

```
for i in *;do
    rpm --queryformat "%{NAME} %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{SourceRPM}  %{Summary} %{Group} %{URL} %{ARCH}" -qp  "$i"   ;
    echo ;
done  >> x.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just append newline by yourself.

The correct answer is this:

```
rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}\n" > app.list
```